# Troubles with Python and YUM on CentOS 7.5

Tags: python, centos, yum, rpm

I have a problem with yum istallation.

Yum needs Python:

```
rpm -i yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch
```

Python needs Python libraries:

```
rpm -i python-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by python-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64
        python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-68.el6_10 is needed by python-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64
```

Python libraries need expat library (and Python itself! the circle is closed!):

```
rpm -i python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
warning: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libexpat.so.1(EXPAT_2_0_1_RH)(64bit) is needed by python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
        libffi.so.5()(64bit) is needed by python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
        libgdbm.so.2()(64bit) is needed by python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
        python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
```

But expat is already installed:

```
rpm -i expat-2.0.1-13.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
warning: expat-2.0.1-13.el6_8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
        package expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64 (which is newer than expat-2.0.1-13.el6_8.x86_64) is already installed
        file /lib64/libexpat.so.1 from install of expat-2.0.1-13.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64
        file /usr/bin/xmlwf from install of expat-2.0.1-13.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64
```

I don't know how to fix that. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1) Just install them all at once:

```
rpm -i yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm python-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
```

2) You need a package which provides `libexpat.so.1(EXPAT_2_0_1_RH)(64bit)`. Check what your package provides `rpm -q --provides expat`